# Logic behind two consecutive heads/tails

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

We play a game with a fair coin where we toss $N$ amount of times before we get a consecutive head or consecutive tails. What is the expected number of rolls ($N$)?

My solution differed from that of the textbooks - which argued the expectation is $$ \sum_{2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1},$$ however my logic was $$ \frac{1}{2}(2) + \frac{1}{2}(x+1) = x $$ where $\frac{1}{2}(2)$ is the the choice where you roll two consecutive numbers, and the $\frac{1}{2}(x+1)$ is the choice where you roll a non-consecutive, meaning you would have to roll again.
Both answers gave $3$; however I am concerned if my logic is incorrect for my solution or if I found an alternate solution.

Comment: What if you roll HTHTHTHTHTT?

Comment: The quote from the textbook solution originally read $\sum\limits_2^{inf} .5k^{k-1}$. I think the first $k$ was a typo and it really should have meant $(.5)^{k-1}$ rather than the $\frac{k^{k-1}}2$ that @Leucippus corrected it to.

Comment: @Troposphere   yes, that would make the sum less complicated.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork wouldn't that adhere to my logic was to why we have (x+1) amount of rolls - meaning that if we don't land two consecutive number's and stop the recursive - we continue tacking on another roll

Comment: So you think your expectation should go *up* for such long sequences??